# java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast javax.swing.JPanel to java.lang.Boolean

Tags: java, netbeans

Me sale ese error al ejecutar JFrame en el cual se encuentra Jpanel. Alguna idea que me den porqué se produce esto sería de gran ayuda.

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast javax.swing.JPanel to java.lang.Boolean
>       at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3369)
>       at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding.convertForward(Binding.java:1312)
>       at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding.getSourceValueForTarget(Binding.java:844)
>       at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding.refreshUnmanaged(Binding.java:1222)
>       at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding.refresh(Binding.java:1207)
>       at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.tryRefreshThenSave(AutoBinding.java:162)
>       at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.bindImpl(AutoBinding.java:199)
>       at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding.bindUnmanaged(Binding.java:959)
>       at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding.bind(Binding.java:944)
>       at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup.bind(BindingGroup.java:143)
>       at enterprise_systro.VENTA.initComponents(VENTA.java:1437)
>       at enterprise_systro.VENTA.(VENTA.java:33)
>       at enterprise_systro.VENTA$53.run(VENTA.java:2252)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: ¿tienes el código dónde falla?

Comment: me marca que error está en esta ejecución generada por Netbeans:     bindingGroup.bind();

Comment: Te lo está marcando aquí VENTA.java:1437

Comment: La solución encontré aquí. Muchas gracias a todos. : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684271/bindinggroup-issue-in-java-netbeans-7-0

Answer (score 0):

El fragmento de código de error...

Cannot cast javax.swing.JPanel to java.lang.Boolean

te indica que estas tratando de "Castear"(Convertir o pasar datos de un tipo, a otro tipo de dato)  en este caso un JPanel (elemento visual) a un tipo boolean (cierto o falso) Lo cual por lógica es imposible.